# How can I stop multiple forms from opening?

Tags: c#, foreach, listbox, break, selectedindex

What is happening here is that when I click on someone that is a Student in myListBox to open their details, a windows form showing their details will show up and so would a windows form showing showing the details for the first Teacher that is in myListBox.

If I click on a Teacher in myListBox just a windows form would open up for them which is what I want. How can I get it to work like this for the people that are Student? Is it possible for me to do something that would be like:

```
 if(myListBox.SelectedIndex == Student)
 {
    //code to open details form here
 }
```

This is how I open the details Form for people. If I didnt use the if statement that says myListBox.SelectedIndex == index. Then a details form for everyone will open.

```
private void openInfoButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            int index = 0;
            foreach (Student student in studentsList)
            {
                if (myListBox.SelectedIndex == index)
                {
                    PersonDetails studentDetails = new PersonDetails(student);
                    studentDetails.Show();
                    break;
                }
                index++;
            }

            foreach (Teacher teacher in teacherList)
            {
                if (myListBox.SelectedIndex == index)
                {
                    PersonDetails teacherDetails = new PersonDetails(teacher);
                    teacherDetails.Show();
                    break;
                }
                index++;
            }
}
```

Comment: Well you are telling it to `studentDetails.Show()` inside of a foreach Loop.. what else did you expect..?

Comment: It's called a `Debugger`, use it and you'll see wonders

Comment: @DJKRAZE where else could I put it? if I  create the instace outside it wouldnt detect student so there wont be any details for the form to display when it opens? I apologise if I am wrong and please correct me if I am

Comment: Perhaps you could setup a Switch Statement and like Dan Pichelman has mentioned, to capture the Button this is your code / your design perhaps you should rethink the design as it currently stands without knowing what your requirements are , it would be like the `Blind leading the Blind` in your case..

Comment: `switch (((Button)sender).Name)
{
  //case statement goes in here
}` something like this if you wanted to know which button otherwise you need to really provide more specific information

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the `sender` object, it'll tell you which button was clicked.  From there you should know whether to display the Student or Teacher form